# Choosing the right preposition when there are multiple adjectives modifying the noun

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, prepositions, adjectives

When we want to be specific, we can have two separate prepositions following two different adjectives. Such as:

*... can be either **supportive of** or **perilous for** a noun.*

But, can we choose to only have the preposition for the last adjective modifying the noun?

*... can ideologically be either welcoming (towards) or very skeptical **of** change.*

Comment: You can *choose* to do so, but it won't be as commonly accepted.

Comment: Most people will be doubtful or unsupportive of mixed prepositions wrongly applied. But choosing the adjectives wisely will be conducive and helpful to a satisfactory outcome.